# How to use Objective C static framework inside swift iOS swift cocoa framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am trying to write a iOS Cocoa Touch framework in swift and trying to use some old Objective C static libraries.

I am unable to use any of the header files from static library. It says "Use of undeclared type [image]"

I have gone through couple of threads in stack overflow before posting this thread.
1) Tried adding birding file - it complains that birding files are not supported in frameworks
2) Tried making the headers as public instead of project
3) Tried "allow_non_modular_includes_in_framework_modules"

Not sure what is that i am missing..

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you provide some basic information? For example if the bridging file caused error, what is the error message? What do you mean by point 2? Any screen shot?

Comment: The error says "Use of undeclared type SQLEngine. Swift file is unable to recognize the header file which came along with objective c static library.
This issue is fixed now, Mistake I did is that i have not imported the header in umbrella file and trying to create Bridging Header, Later I learned that We cannot create birding headers inside Swift Frameworks.

Answer (score -1):

Found the fix, Need to import the Header in umbrella file. Then Xcode is able to build without errors

Comment: Can you post your umbrella file please (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27373554/using-objective-c-code-from-ios-cocoa-static-library-project-with-swift-code-in)).