# Using Objective-C code in iOS Cocoa Static Library project with Swift code in iOS Application project

Tags: xcode, swift, import, static-libraries, xcode6.1

I am looking for a simple procedure for combining an Objective-C code from a shared library project with Swift code from an application project but have had no success so far with this sequence:

1. start Xcode 6.1.1
2. create workspace Test
3. create iOS Cocoa Touch Static Library project TestLibrary and add it to workspace
4. create iOS Single View Application project Test (language: Swift) and add it to workspace
5. add `import TestLibrary` to ViewController.swift

If I now build Test, I receive this error in ViewController.swift: `No such module: ‘TestLibrary’`.

Presumably two hurdles must be overcome:

1. Tell TestLibrary that is should "export" TestLibrary.h. What is the right syntax and procedure for adding the (presumably) required [bridging header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27157154/importing-header-file-from-other-project-in-same-app-target-into-bridging-head) file?
2. Tell Test where TestLibrary is located. Since both the application and static library projects belong to the same workspace (and sit in the file system next to each other) I assume no explicit steps are required, or are there?

So in summary, my question is this: how can I overcome the build error even if I subsequently add `let test = TestLibrary()` to ViewController.swift, i.e. how can Test (Swift code base) make use of TestLibrary (Objective-C code base)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This procedure seems to work (for single app target):

1. Do not add `import TestLibrary`, since both the Swift and Objective-C code will reside in the same app target
2. Create Test-Bridging-Header.h to Test and add `#import "TestLibrary/TestLibrary.h"`
3. Set build setting `Objective-C Bridging Header: Test/Test-Bridging-Header.h` for Test
4. Drag libTestLibrary.a from TestLibrary (under Products) into Test's Link Library With Binaries (under Build Phases)
5. Add `let test = TestLibrary()` e.g. inside `viewDidLoad`in ViewController.swift

Voila ...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have to add all the .h file's of the Framework in the Bridging file, that fixed the issue. Also remove the import TestLibrary from the swift files